# How do I add an object created array to a listbox with the appropriate name?

Tags: c#, listbox

I am trying to add an object to a listbox. However, when I add the item, I am presented with a name such as "System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: newArray".

My code is split into two parts.

```
namespace newApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void createArrayButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //so here i will have on button click it will create a new object of CreateArray
            //start with the name of the array
            CreateArray newArray = new CreateArray();
            newArray.setNameOfArray(newArrayName.ToString());
            newArray.setArraySize(numOfElements);

            //now add the newarray to the list
            string name = newArray.getArrayName();

            arrayList.Items.Add(string.Format(name, newArray.getArrayName()));
            //i have tried other methods of adding the array to the "arrayList listbox", to no avail.
        }   
    }
}
```

Second part:

```
namespace newApp
{
    class CreateArray
    {
        private string arrayName;
        private int arraySize;

        public void setNameOfArray(string nameOfArray)
        {
            arrayName = nameOfArray;            
        }

        public void setArraySize(TextBox all)
        {

            if ((Int32.TryParse(all.Text, out arraySize)))
            {
                arraySize = Int32.Parse(all.Text);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error, garbage value entered\n" +
                    " in 'Elements in array' field.");
            }
        }

        public string getArrayName()
        {
            return arrayName;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: As for the question itself, you have failed to provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem. In particular, the declaration of `newArrayName` and its initialization are missing, even though that variable appears to be _the_ crucial variable in your question. That said, if `newArrayName` is a `TextBox` (as I suspect it is), then you should be passing `newArrayName.Text` as the `nameOfArray` parameter, and not `newArrayName.ToString()`.

Comment: It's still not clear what you want even if you fix that, because the `string.Format()` call makes no sense (you're passing `name` as the format, but it has no format specifiers in it and is exactly the same value as the format argument you pass as well), but at least you'll get something closer to what you wanted.

Comment: Changing newArray.setNameOfArray(newArrayName.ToString());
to newArray.setNameOfArray(newArrayName.Text);
and
arrayList.Items.Add(newArrayName.Text) worked. 

I'm not sure why I didn't even think of trying that. As it seems so obvious now.